# ReactNative - Firebase Realtime Database: Updating the last message in chat list whenever user sends/receives a message

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, chat

I am trying to build a chat app using react native and firebase realtime database. I have implemented the one to one chat however I am having an issue in displaying the list of active chats on homepage.
It displays the chats just fine but I want the last message to automatically get updated whenever some user sends or gets a message, can someone tell me how I can achieve that.

[image: current chat list] This is where I want to update the last message.

[image: users table in database]
[image: chatrooms table]

This is the code that I have tried. It gets a list of all friends of a user and then for each friend it checks whether their chatroom has messages and if messages are present is gets the last message and time and pushes it into an array of objects which I later iterate using Flatlist. My last message doesn't get updated until I reload the app myself. How do I go about this please help

```
const getActiveChatrooms = () => {
    let activeChats = [];
    let completedRequests = 0;
    friends?.forEach((friend) => {
      const chatroomRef = query(
        ref(database, `chatrooms/${friend.chatroomid}`)
      );
      onValue(chatroomRef, (snapshot) => {
        const chatroom = snapshot.val();
        if (chatroom && chatroom.messages) {
          const messages = Object.values(chatroom.messages);
          const lastmsg = messages[messages.length - 1].text;
          const msgtime = messages[messages.length - 1].createdAt;
          activeChats.push({ friend: friend, msg: lastmsg?lastmsg:'Image', time: msgtime });
        }
        //Loop is synchronous db is asynchronous so we need to keep track of how many requests have been completed
        completedRequests++;
        if (completedRequests === user.friends.length) {
          setChats(activeChats);
        }
      });
    });
  };


  const getFriends = () => {
   const dbRef= ref(database, `users/${user.uid}/friends`);
   onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
      const friends = snapshot.val();
      setFriends(friends);
    });
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      getFriends();
    }
  }, [user],[]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (friends) {
      getActiveChatrooms();
    }
    
  }, [friends]);
```